# Google Analytics Data API: missing flag for identifying `golden` data

Tags: google-api, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I've been using such API for generating reports over Google Analytics:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet

This API has result field `isDataGolden`:

```
Indicates if response to this request is golden or not. Data is golden when the exact same request will not produce any new results if asked at a later point in time.
```

---

Currently Google Analytics has new API for generating such reports:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/batchRunReports

But there is no analogue of `isDataGolden` field in this API

## Question:

**Is such flag will be added to new API, or maybe there is another instrument to get only golden data from new API?**

*p.s.:
I need to use this new API, since old one does not support new analytics properties without Universal Analytics `view_id`*

Answer (score 1):

The Google analytics data api is used for extracting data from google analytics ga4 accounts.  The reporting api is used for extracting data from Universal analytics accounts.  These are two different systems and should not be compared.  You can not use the Google analytics data api to extract data from universal analytics accounts with view ids.

If you check the documentation for [RunReportResponse](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/RunReportResponse) which is the response returned from running a reporting in google analytics data.  You will find that there is no is golden property or any property of that nature.

Remember this api is still in beta the team is still working on it.  One may appear in the future.   You will need to wait to find out if google will add any field like this in the future as anyone who would know is probably under NDA and cant tell you.

Comment: On top of this great answer, my guess is that if/when such a property appears it will probably be available under the `metadata` property of the RunReportResponse.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/ResponseMetaData